# XMLreader php обработка ошибок

Tags: php, xml

заметил такую ошибку, если в файле есть дубль закрывающего тега DocBody, то ридер не может получить его данные:

```
  while ($z->read()) {

    if ($z->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && strtolower($z->localName) == 'docbody')
      $body = $z->readOuterXml(); // сыпаться ошибки warning
    }

  }
```

пример файла XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Container>
  <DocumentID>ID</DocumentID>
  <ContainerDoc>
    <DocBody>
      <!-- тут данные -->
    </DocBody>
     </DocBody>
  </ContainerDoc>
</Container>
```

можно как то выкрутиться на такой случай? потому как может быть дубль другого тега...

Comment: Может на валидность проверять? http://php.net/manual/ru/xmlreader.isvalid.php

Comment: Откройте для себя Tidy. Этот инструмент работает как в консоли, так и есть [библиотека под PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/intro.tidy.php). Он исправил вашу невалидную разметку.

Comment: попробую с этим Tidy разобраться, нашел примеры

Comment: попробовал, он все мои теги режет и вставляет html body  кароч делает мне html документ

Comment: Ооо получилось, конфиг взял отсюда и все норм http://php.net/manual/ru/tidy.repairstring.php